# SPF TXT records - do I need to include sub domains for an outsourced sender SPF record

Tags: spf

Say that I want to send mail from my own servers at example.com.

As I understand it, I can specify the following SPF record and have any server addressed by an A record under example.com included by the SPF record. So evaluation of mail sent from mailserver1.example.com, mailserver2.example.com would result in a pass:

`v=spf1 a ~all`

If however I am using an outsourced mail sender say wesendmail.com, I would use an SPF record like this:

`v=spf1 include:wesendmail.com ~all`

My main question is - If wesendmail.com sends mail from servers at mailserver1.wesendmail.com, mailserver2.wesendmail.com, do I need to include additional SPF records for these servers, or are they captured by the above SPF record?

Also, if I do need to include additional records, how would I find out what their mail servers are? NSLOOKUP domain transfer attempts are blocked by most DNS servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `include` clause in your SPF record fetches the corresponding SPF record from wesendmail.com and *includes* that in-line in your record. So assuming that wesendmail configures their record correctly, you don't need to do anything further.

Comment: I think this is an excellent answer, but would add a caveat that **SPF is completely pointless if you finish with `~all`**.  You can find big-time sysadmins on SF who treat `~all` as grounds for rejection.  If you're going to bother with SPF at all, **please fully-enumerate your sending servers, and finish up with `-all`**.

Comment: Your comment regarding ~/- is backed up here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sender-id.html

Comment: "... includes that in-line in your record." Is that true? [RFC7208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.2) says: "Only the evaluated result of the referenced SPF record is used, rather than literally including the mechanisms of the referenced record in the first."